# Is there a way to signal to fragment view that data has been passed into argument?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to develop an app where I have spinner in fragment(first fragment), to update spinner options user has to open a dialog window(second fragment) and put input in there. Data is passed through interface as a bundle and then into first fragment arguments.  My spinner is in first fragment view so I couldn't figure out how to call a first argument view function from second argument, instead inside first argument view I constantly check if the arguments are updated, something like this

```
  if(!displayedText.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                updateListSpinner()
                arguments?.clear()
            }
```

so in fragment view I constantly check if arguments were updated and then I clear them, everything works as it should but I just wonder what's better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Fragment Result Listeners. More documentation: [Communicating between fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate). So in your instance, whenever the user interacts with the dialog fragment, send a result to the first fragment, which will be registered to use the data and you can update your spinner.

Here is some working code that controls navigation in my app:

In second fragment:

```
open fun navigate(idOfDestination: Int, bundle: Bundle?) {
    val tempBundle = bundle ?: Bundle()
    tempBundle.putInt(NAVIGATION_DESTINATION, idOfDestination)
    activity?.supportFragmentManager?.setFragmentResult(NAVIGATION_RESULT, tempBundle)
}
```

In target fragment (which in your case would be the first fragment), register the listener:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    activity?.supportFragmentManager?.setFragmentResultListener(NAVIGATION_RESULT, this, FragmentResultListener { _, bundle ->
        val destination = bundle.getInt(NAVIGATION_DESTINATION)
        bundle.remove(NAVIGATION_DESTINATION)
        navigationHandler(bundle,destination)
    })
}

private fun navigationHandler(bundle: Bundle?, idOfDestination: Int) {
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(binding.root)
    if (!FeatureControlManager.isDestinationAllowedToGo(idOfDestination)) {
        navController = childFragmentManager.fragments.first().findNavController()
    }
    navController.validateAndNavigate(navController, idOfDestination, childFragmentManager, bundle)
}
```

Comment: That works with viewmodel am I right? I was trying to implement it just with interface without mvvm but I guess mvvm is the best approach for fragment communication?

Comment: @Michal, no this is just fragments, you don't need ViewModel.

Comment: supportFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener is not available now in 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0'

Comment: I think they are: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.fragment/fragment-ktx as of Feb 21.